# Справочник методов Python

Tags: python

Есть ли где нибудь краткий справочник методов встроенных типов данных Python?
Чтоб о каждом методе одной-двумя строками
или только юзать dir() и help() ?

Comment: Я юзаю bpython. Там удобная подсветка, автоматический help из docstrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/

Comment: dir() и help() по сути то же самое, но удобнее
но я же сказал, что мне интересно не это

Answer (score 1):

А почему не быть до конца поклонником питона и написать что то вида

```
for i in dir():
    help(i)
```

Если захотеть - можно вывести в текстовый файл, отформатировать, отфильтровать. Дальше - только фантазия.